# How to Intercept requests in Atlassian Forge applications?

Tags: node.js, express, atlassian-forge

I am exploring on building Atlassian Forge apps in Jira Cloud. In order to intercept a request and then modify the response for that particular request, I was thinking of using Express JS as middleware. To try that out, I wrote a basic Express JS code in index.js file of the but the app is giving the "process.cwd not a function error."[the snapshot of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt61s.png)

Is it even possible to intercept any coming request and modify the response in Atlassian Forge applications?